# Can I use dict.pop in map function. python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.6

I want to exclude keys from dict. I have script like this:

```
#! .env/bin/pythoin3.6
d = {1:"a", 2: "b", 3: "c", 4: "d", 5: "v"}   
exclude = [1, 3]

map(d.pop, exclude)
print("Map result {}".format(d))

d = {1:"a", 2: "b", 3: "c", 4: "d", 5: "v"}   
exclude = [1, 3]

for k in exclude: 
    d.pop(k)

print("Result of 'for k in ...' {}".format(d))
```

It returns this:

```
Map result {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd', 5: 'v'}
Result of 'for k in ...' {2: 'b', 4: 'd', 5: 'v'}
```

As you can see second result is correct.But first is not.

**Can I use dict.pop in map function?**

Comment: `map` is lazy. Until something makes it run it won't do anything. In your specific case, no calls to `pop` will be made. Wrap it in `list()` for one way to force it to run.

Comment: `map` is specifically to return new values, and abusing it when you don't need any return values is, well, abusing it.

Comment: I wrapped it in list() and it works. thank you @Jim Fasarakis Hilliard

Comment: Glad I helped, but, take note of what deceze said, this isn't really the way to use map.